# How to use Google Cloud Run ENV variables in local development environment?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-sdk

How to use Google Cloud Run ENV variables in local development environment?

I have a Google Cloud Run deployment with ENV variables that I created inside Google Cloud Console.

[image: ENV Variable inside cloud run]

I installed the Google Cloud SDK in order to be able to test my code locally, everything seems to be working besides the ENV variables, for example when I do:

```
BUCKET = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME')
print(f'Bucket Name from Environment Variable: {BUCKET}')
```

It prints:

```
Bucket Name from Environment Variable: None
```

I also tried to set .env file with this variable and same thing happens:

```
Bucket Name from Environment Variable: None
```

So how should I use it locally?

Comment: Environment variable are.... environment variable! Set them in your environment, run your code and your variable are there! If you don't see the variable it's because your runtime environment is not correctly set. Share how you configure it

Comment: For some reason it is not working, I configured my environment variable inside the Google Cloud Run ENV variables set I will add an image to the post

Comment: i use load_dotenv (pip install python-dotenv) and then ex. SPREADSHEET_ID=os.getenv('SPREADSHEET_ID_ENV')

Comment: Do you have things in your container that override the value? Can you share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the only reason it did not work is because I did not have python-dotenv installed:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Thank you!